# Order of setting Schedulers in Rx

Tags: rx-java, kotlin, reactive-programming

I'm really new to Rx, just wondering how does the order of `subscribeOn` impact `Observable`

```
//This will not print anything
Observable.just("whatever")
        .flatMap { s -> Observable.just(s.length) }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe(::println)

//This prints the length
Observable.just("whatever")
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .flatMap { s -> Observable.just(s.length) }
        .subscribe(::println)
```

What happend under the hood and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RxJava Schedulers use daemon threads which may stop or not run at all if the "main" thread of Java exits. When I run both setups, sometimes the second doesn't print anything either, sometimes it does; it is probabilistic you see something or not.

It really depends on how fast the `newThread` reacts and executes the code upstream. For the second case, since it has a longer set of subscriptions happening on the main thread, the time the execution returns after the `subscribe`, the `newThread` may have enough time to trigger the print.

If you put `Thread.sleep(1000)` you'll see both print the value.

Answer (score 2):

Actually both of them print the result. The only difference is the timing. This is what I believe to be the explanation to the behavior observed - In first case, `flatMap` is directly subscribed to the result of `just` on `main` thread and `println` on a new thread. Spawning a new thread and `println` both being intensive operations take time to execute and the `main` thread exits before that.

In second case, `flatMap` subscribes to `just` on a new thread and `println` subscribes to `flatMap` on `main` thread. Thus, `main` thread is kept more occupied due to dependency post spawning a new thread and we see the result before `main` exits.

You can attempt to execute the same with the below code in last line to see the difference.

```
Observable.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS).toBlocking().subscribe();
```